# How to determine version numbers of modules of atom plugins

Tags: atom-editor, js-beautify

I'm using the atom-beautify plugin for the Atom Editor.  Recently it started ignoring `/* beautify preserve:start */` in my JavaScript files.  The plugin (not Atom) should be using JS Beautify by default, so I suspect the bug was introduced there.  I'm not really sure.  I'd like to track it down, but realized I don't know how to determine which module that a plugin is using.  Is there a development feature of Atom that would allow me to enumerate all the plugins and their dependency versions?

Answer (score 0):

`apm list -g` will display all Atom packages and their versions.

`npm list -g` will display all of the Node packages along with their versions and dependencies.

As far as the root of your question, have you looked for a relevant setting in the `atom-beautify` package settings? (Settings > atom-beautify > Settings > JavaScript)